# ImportError: API_KEY

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

[image]

Hi, I am getting an error while importing API_KEY, please advise.

Comment: what is this config file/package? You need to be very specific about it.

Comment: am able to resolve it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you observe the path of **config** file in the error description, it's pointing to some library in site-packages. It's not your `config.py` file.

You need to give the correct path to your config file.

P.S: Using Python files like `config.py` is not the best way to store the configurations. I would recommend to use `dotenv` or some other configuration helper packages.

Answer (score 0):

From the code `from config import API_KEY` , you are trying to import `API_KEY` from a [Pypi package]"https://pypi.org/project/config/". If you want to use config.py for getting API_KEY try to use other config methods like `ConfigParser`